# Scala advanced loop

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop

```
  var z = 10
  for (i <- 1 to 3; x = i + 1; y = z - 1) {
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1
  }
```

Output:

2
9
3
9
4
9

It is not what I expect. It seems the for loop always keeps z = 10. Can someone help me explain this?

Comment: Why do you think z is always 10? Try printing it to see what it is...

Comment: It doesn't keep `z = 10`, but it *does* keep `y = 9` ;)

Comment: see my answer. also, it's called for comprehension.

Comment: You can edit your answer to improve it if. Immutability is only good for development, not for SO questions :) Try to understand how `for` comprehension works. If you are new to Scala, try avoiding `var`s until you get a good grasp of Collections and `for` comprehensions (even after that you probably won't need `var`s).

Comment: Thank you guys. I have known what happens under the hood :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect what you are running as following:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
scala> import ru._
scala> q"""for (i <- 1 to 3; x = i + 1; y = z - 1) {
     |     println(x)
     |     println(y)
     |     z -= 1
     |   }
     | """
res13: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree =
1.to(3).map(((i) => {
  val x = i.$plus(1);
  val y = z.$minus(1);
  scala.Tuple3(i, x, y)
})).foreach(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
  case scala.Tuple3((i @ _), (x @ _), (y @ _)) => {
    println(x);
    println(y);
    z.$minus$eq(1)
  }
}))
```

If you see the expanded code, I believe it should be enough to convince you that `y` should always be 9.

Comment: Thank you! Got it!

Comment: I'm not sure what's more intimidating: this desugared code, or the fact that the OP immediately "got it" ;)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin why is it intimidating? OP does not entirely lack the knowledge of the language. that's why i judge looking at desugared code would be enough for OP to understand what's undergoing. otherwise pointing to a page, e.g. https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html , would achieve the same effect.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin if you want to see some psychology in play, i can carefully describe how i can perceive what quality OP has by destructing his wordings and interpreting the way he approach his question. it's clear to me OP's reached certain level that does not require hand holding.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin is this answer hard to understand? When you see "map" in this answer, it's clear why y is always 9 under the hood. Where does your sense of superiority come from?

Comment: @梁嘉腾 I'll simply go through the question and the answer, and match up the used language features with the pages from Odersky's book "Programming in Scala" (1st ed.): integer arithmetic (p.24),`println` (p.25), `var` (p.26), `for` (p.34). On the other hand, the answer contained: operators as methods (p.40), translating `for` loops to `map+foreach` (without any comment) (p.484), function literals (p.143, foreshadowed p.34), pattern matching with variable binding (p.277), annotations (p.506),  introduced by calls to reflection library (not mentioned in 1st ed.).  Summary: Q=(24,34), A=(40,506).

Comment: @梁嘉腾 ... Therefore, it seemed to me as if the answer used a lot of features that someone who got through the first ten pages of "First steps in Scala" wouldn't necessarily understand. I *personally* don't find the desugared code self-explanatory, it somehow lacks  the "pythonic" pseudocode-feeling. I had to walk through the rewriting steps to convince myself that holding `y` fixed is indeed the intended compiler behavior. I don't know why you think that admitting that I find a piece of code "intimidating" is somehow a sign of "superiority", it's actually exactly the opposite.

Comment: @梁嘉腾 HuStmpHrrr has explained to me how he inferred from the question that the OP (you) must be much further than first ten pages in the Scala book. HuStmpHrrr has even hypothetized that the OP (you) must know at least one another language like Java. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to pick up those subtle linguistic cues from your question. I apologize if my answer turned out to be too long and too full of unnecessary details, boring you out of your mind with basics was not my intent.

Answer (score 2):

Scala's `for` are not imperative loops, they are general *monadic comprehensions*. Every `for` and `for-yield` is rewritten into a sequence of applications of methods `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap` and `withFilter`.

For example, this here:

```
for (x <- generator) yield { f(x) }
```

is rewritten into

```
generator.map(x => f(x))
```

If you use definitions like `x = ...` inside of `for`-comprehensions, they are rewritten as follows:

```
for {
  g <- generator
  x = xRhs
} {
  doBlah()
}
```

is rewritten to

```
for {
  (g, x) <- for (g <- generator) yield (g, xRhs)
} {
  doBlah()
}
```

and then to

```
(for (g <- generator) yield (g,xRhs)).foreach{ 
  case (g, x) => doBlah() 
}
```

and finally to

```
generator.map(g => (g, xRhs)).foreach{ case (g, x) => doBlah() }
```

For your example it means the following horrific rewriting sequence (copy-paste it, run it, try to follow each rewriting step):

```
def ----- : Unit = println("-" * 40)

{
  var z = 10
  for (i <- 1 to 3; x = i + 1; y = z - 1) {
    // println(s"i = $i , x = $x , y = $y, z = $z")
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1
  }
}

-----

{
  var z = 10
  for {
    (i, x) <- for (i <- 1 to 3) yield (i, i + 1)
    y = z - 1
  } {
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1 
  }
}

-----

{
  var z = 10
  for {
    ((i, x), y) <- for ((i, x) <- for (i <- 1 to 3) yield (i, i + 1)) yield ((i, x), z - 1)
  } {
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1 
  }
}

-----

{
  var z = 10
  for {
    ((i, x), y) <- for ((i, x) <- (1 to 3).map(i => (i, i + 1))) yield ((i, x), z - 1)
  } {
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1
  }
}

-----

{
  var z = 10
  for {
    ((i, x), y) <- (1 to 3).map(i => (i, i + 1)).map(ix => (ix, z - 1))
  } {
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1
  }
}

-----

{
  var z = 10
  (1 to 3).map(i => (i, i + 1)).map(ix => (ix, z - 1)).foreach {
    case ((i, x), y) => 
      println(x)
      println(y)
      z -= 1
  }
}
```

The final result is (morally equivalent to) something like this:

```
  var z = 10
  (1 to 3).map(i => (i, i + 1)).map(ix => (ix, z - 1)).foreach {
    case ((i, x), y) => 
      println(x)
      println(y)
      z -= 1
  }
```

As you can see, the `z - 1` in the second `map` is evaluated even before the `foreach`-iteration starts. Therefore `y` remains stuck at `9`.

How to avoid it? Just avoid using `var`s in combination with `for`-comprehensions. Better: use `var`s sparingly in general. Or at least, move them inside the block:

```
  var z = 10
  for (i <- 1 to 3) {
    val x = i + 1
    val y = z - 1
    println(x)
    println(y)
    z -= 1
  }
```

Comment: Andrey, when you say, "...is rewritten into..." is there something that shows that, or is there a description somewhere on how it's done?

Comment: @DonBranson I've attempted to follow the rewriting rules presented in Odersky et al. "Programming In Scala" 23.4 (Translation of for expressions). E.g. it says (quote): "`for (x <- expr1; y = expr2; seq) yield expr3` [...] is translated to [...]`for((x,y) <- for(x<-expr1) yield (x, expr2); seq) yield expr3`". As HuStmpHrrr's answer shows, the rules in the book are a bit simplified, the current compiler implementaion seems to do some further optimizations. But the rules in the book seem to be good enough for understanding the semantics of the for-comprehensions.