# for comprehension fails when using an intermediate variable

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

[Scastie version](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Sciss/gTx4dm1ZQd6LA40zdqAtKQ)

With this infra-structure:

```
trait Pat[A]
object Pat {
  def apply[A](elems: A*): Pat[A] = ???
}

implicit class PatOps[A](p: Pat[A]) {
  def ++ (that: Pat[A]): Pat[A] = ???

  def bubble: Pat[Pat[A]] = ???

  def grouped(size: Pat[Int]): Pat[Pat[A]] = ???
}

implicit class PatPatOps[A](p: Pat[Pat[A]]) {
  def map[B](f: Pat[A] => Pat[B]): Pat[Pat[B]] = ???

  def flatMap[B](f: Pat[A] => Pat[B]): Pat[B] = ???

  def flatten: Pat[A] = ???
}
```

It is possible to write the following for-comprehension:

```
trait Test1 {
  val lPat = Pat(1, 2, 3)
  val xs = for {
    len     <- lPat.bubble
    cantus  <- Pat(4, 40, 3).grouped(len)
  } yield {
    cantus ++ Pat(-1)
  }
  xs.flatten
}
```

But this one, using an intermediate variable, fails:

```
trait Test2 {
  val lPat = Pat(1, 2, 3)
  val xs = for {
    len     <- lPat.bubble  // XXX
    brown = Pat(4, 40, 3)
    cantus  <- brown.grouped(len)
  } yield {
    cantus ++ Pat(-1)
  }
  xs.flatten
}
```

The error for the line marked XXX is:

> ```
> type mismatch;
>  found   : (Playground.this.Pat[Int], Playground.this.Pat[Int])
>  required: Playground.this.Pat[?]
> ```

Scala is 2.12.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when you define `map` with overly restrictive signature `map[B](f: Pat[A] => Pat[B])`. Recall that usually, it is supposed to accept functions with arbitrary result type `B`, that is, it's supposed to be rather something like:

```
map[B](f: A => B): <stuff>
```

Now, your for-comprehension with intermediate helper variable `brown`

```
  val xs = for {
    len     <- lPat.bubble
    brown = Pat(4, 40, 3)
    cantus  <- brown.grouped(len)
  } yield {
    cantus ++ Pat(-1)
  }
```

is rewritten using a `map` into

```
  val xs = lPat.bubble.map(((len) => {
    val brown = Pat(4, 40, 3);
    scala.Tuple2(len, brown)
  })).flatMap(((x$1) => x$1: @scala.unchecked match {
    case scala.Tuple2((len @ _), (brown @ _)) => 
      brown.
        grouped(len).
        map(((cantus) => cantus.$plus$plus(Pat(-1))))
  }))
```

as described in [the documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) or [in my overly detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938486/scala-advanced-loop/48938914#48938914).

Note how the return type of the implicitly generated `map` is now something like `(Pat[A], Pat[Int])` (the type of the tuple `(len, brown)`), and doesn't match the pattern `Pat[B]` from your declaration.

I don't see any workarounds. Just do whatever you can to avoid defining `map` as `map[B](f: Pat[A] => Pat[B])`, otherwise it will behave way too strangely. Avoid breaking functoriality of `map`. If your `Pat[X]` cannot `map` `f: X => Y` to a `Pat[Y]` for arbitrary `X` and `Y`, then don't call it `map`.

---

**Edit: there is always a work-around...**

One thing you could do is to introduce some kind of implicitly supplied `CanPatFrom`:

```
trait CanPatFrom[X, A] extends (X => Pat[A])
```

and then

```
...
def map[X, B](f: Pat[A] => X)(implicit cpf: CanPatFrom[X, B]) = {
  val pb: Pat[B] = cpf(f(...))
  /* do your stuff here with `Pat[B]` instead of 
   * generic `X`
   */
  ...
}
```

Assuming that your `Pat` carries some kind of cartesian-monoidal structure, you could define

- `CanPatFrom[Pat[A], Pat[A]]`,
- `CanPatFrom[(Pat[A], Pat[B]), Pat[(A, B)]]`,
- `CanPatFrom[(Pat[A], Pat[B], Pat[C]), Pat[(A, B, C)]]`,
- ...

and thereby obtain a `map` that can at least cope with the case that the return type is a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for lifting the mystery of the tuple coming into the picture. I'll see if I move `map` back to `PatOps` using an implicit `ev: A <:< Pat[_]`. I did that initially but moved to `PatPatOps` to avoid `asInstanceOf` calls.

Comment: Yeah, as I prediced, getting lots of `missing type parameter` errors on the code base now, meaning the type inference breaks down; so I guess I stick to `PatPatOps` and have inferior for-comprehension support :-/

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off of Andrey Tyukin's answer, another thing you can do with implicits is assert that some type parameter satisfies some constraint. For example, we can assert that a parameter `A` is a subclass of `Pat[A1]` for some other parameter `A1`. Here's the code:

```
object Pats extends App {

  trait Pat[A]
  object Pat {
    def apply[A](elems: A*): Pat[A] = ???
  }

  implicit class PatOps[A](p: Pat[A]) {

    def ++(that: Pat[A]): Pat[A] = ???

    def bubble: Pat[Pat[A]] = ???

    def grouped(size: Pat[Int]): Pat[Pat[A]] = ???

    def map[B, A1, B1](f: A => B)
                      (implicit
                       ev1: A <:< Pat[A1],
                       ev2: B <:< Pat[B1]): Pat[B] = ???

    def flatMap[B, A1, B1](f: A => Pat[B])
                          (implicit
                           ev1: A <:< Pat[A1],
                           ev2: B <:< Pat[B1]): Pat[B] = ???

    def flatten[A1](implicit ev: A <:< Pat[A1]): Pat[A1] = ???
  }

  val lPat = Pat(1, 2, 3)
  val xs = for {
    len <- lPat.bubble
    cantus <- Pat(4, 40, 3).grouped(len)
  } yield cantus ++ Pat(-1)
  xs.flatten
}
```

I wouldn't recommend taking this approach, though, because it violates the usual meaning of `map` and `flatMap`. What I might suggest instead is creating a private class `PatInternal` and completely obfuscate it from the end user.

Comment: Thanks, I had `map` originally defined for `PatOps` with the implicit evidence. But then didn't like that much, because I have insert a horrible `asInstanceOf` in the implementation, which went away when moving forward to `PatPatOps`. Perhaps I should revert that and see what happens next.

Comment: I see. You can't apply the evidence parameter to the elements inside without digging in to the implementation of `Pat`. And since it's a completely abstract trait, there's no way you can know what the implementation is going to be. A puzzle indeed.